# Spring 3, rest controller, mvc:annotation-driven, jdk 6 but spring refuses to send back xml responses

Tags: xml, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

This has been driving me nuts for days now. From what I've read I understand that I have two choices when it comes to auto-handling content with Spring MVC. I can use messageConverters to autodetect the request through @RequestBody and the response through @ResponseBody, or (but not and!)... I can use view resolvers to autodetect based on various other criteria such as request extensions.

I'm trying to use @RequestBody and @ResponseBody. I've read multiple posts here and blogs and I cannot see why this is not working. My spring-servlet.xml file contains:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="au.com.mypackage.service" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public Bean getData(@PathVariable String id) {
        Bean bean = new Bean(); // Simple bean not worth listing here.
        bean.setSomething("hello");
        bean.setSomethingElse(5);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

But the logs

```
...
2011-07-07 17:23:58,119 DEBUG org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService:186 Converted to '123'
2011-07-07 17:23:58,120 DEBUG org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker:173 Invoking request handler method: public au.com.mypackage.service.MyController$Bean au.com.mypackage.service.MyController.getData(java.lang.String)
...
2011-07-07 17:23:58,143 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver:132 Resolving exception from handler [au.com.mypackage.service.MyController@3d3c4c09]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
...
2011-07-07 17:23:58,144 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:824 Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2011-07-07 17:23:58,145 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet:674 Successfully completed request
2011-07-07 17:23:58,150 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:693 DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/spring/data/123]
...
2011-07-07 17:23:58,154 DEBUG org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker:173 Invoking request handler method: public au.com.mypackage.service.MyController$Bean au.com.mypackage.service.MyController.getData(java.lang.String)
2011-07-07 17:23:58,175 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker:981 Written [au.com.mypackage.service.MyController$Bean@5b62f030] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@3c870e2f]
2011-07-07 17:23:58,175 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet:824 Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'smsManager2': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2011-07-07 17:23:58,175 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet:674 Successfully completed request
```

How I read this is:

1. Hits the controller and gets back the bean.
2. Throws a HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.
3. Hits the controller and gets back the bean.
4. Returns it using a JSON message converter.

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong, I've been playing with this for days and cannot get it to send back XML.

I've checked the MessageConverters in the annotationMethodHandlerAdapter and there is a JaxB converter there. So I'm at a loss as to why it's not being used.

I've also set the Accept header in SoapUI's rest request to application/xml and it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
@ResponseBody public Bean getData
```

I think it should be

```
public @ResponseBody Bean getData
```

You're annotating the response type, not the method